# Tinymce is (sometimes) undefined

Tags: jquery-plugins, tinymce

I'm using Tinymce (with jQuery) in a project I'm working at; we use a rich text editor for users to input information; however, sometimes when loading the page Firefox and Chrome will detect a 'tinymce is not defined' error (sometimes at different lines of the code), while other times the page will load just fine. What's weird is that it works perfectly with IE.

Here's a bit of the code I'm using:

```
view.find('textarea.rich-text').each(function () {        
   $(this).tinymce( /* ...rules... */);        
});
```

And later on

```
_variable.find("#summary").tinymce().setContent(content);
```

This line is where the error (sometimes) gets caught. It seems to me that the problem is a loading issue, even though the tinyMCE plugin is initialized about 5000 lines prior this line.

**Update**: For now I have managed to 'solve' the problem with a setTimeout, but this seems like a really ugly way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few points:

- You don't mention whether or not the TinyMCE initialization is done within a jQuery `ready` event function. It should be of course.
- You don't need the each loop. You can just say:

`$('textarea.rich-text').tinymce({
  script_url : '../js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
  theme : "advanced",
  ...
 });`

- You don't need the call to `find` since you are just selecting by id. Just do:

`$("#summary").tinymce().setContent(content);`

- Your real issue is probably that tinymce has not finished initializing itself when you get the error. You see it has to load a script from the configured `script_url`. That may take a while. Therefore, you have to make use of a callback such as [oninit](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aoninit).

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes accordingly, as well as making sure that tinymce was initialized before jquery (I saw on other questions that this was usually a problem), and I'm _still_ getting the same error: `TypeError: $("#summary").tinymce() is undefined`

Comment: So you put that line into the `oninit` callback?

Comment: when I tried to add the function it was supposed to call next, firebug said that there was an 'undefined error'; it didn't recognize the method even though they were on the same page, so I removed it.

Comment: `$('textarea.rich-text').tinymce({
        ...
        oninit : function(){$("#summary").tinymce().setContent(content);}
});`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! I wish I could say this was solved but now the only problem is that the SECOND texteditor (by the name 'backup') raises an error when I try to do the same, that is:
`$('textarea.rich-text').tinymce({ ... oninit : function(){$("#summary").tinymce().setContent(content);
 $("#backup").tinymce().setContent(otherContent);} });`
The error is on the second line; summary loads just fine. Does it need its own function to work?

Comment: **UPDATE**: nevermind; that was a problem with my own code. Thank you for your help! Works great now :)

Comment: +1 for "You don't mention whether or not the TinyMCE initialization is done within a jQuery ready event function. It should be of course." That was my problem, with random "tinyMCE is undefined" errors when including more than one instance in a page. When not queued in the ready() event queue, the lazy load request of tinyMCE's "script_url" option resulted in multiple parallel loads overwriting each other (although I'm not sure why ready() prevents that result).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have control over init method of TinyMCE then, you can follow this solution.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function myCustomSetContent( id, content ) {
        // Check if TinyMCE is defined or not.
        if( typeof tinymce != "undefined" ) {
            var editor = tinymce.get( id );
            // Check if TinyMCE is initialized properly or not.
            if( editor && editor instanceof tinymce.Editor ) {
                editor.setContent( text );
                editor.save( { no_events: true } );
            } else {
                // Fallback
                // If TinyMCE is not initialized then directly set the value in textarea.
                //TinyMCE will take up this value when it gets initialized.
                jQuery( '#'+id ).val( text );
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function myCustomGetContent( id ) {
        // Check if TinyMCE is defined or not.
        if( typeof tinymce != "undefined" ) {
            var editor = tinymce.get( id );
            // Check if TinyMCE is initialized properly or not.
            if( editor && editor instanceof tinymce.Editor ) {
                return editor.getContent();
            } else {
                // Fallback
                // If TinyMCE is not initialized then directly set the value in textarea.
                // TinyMCE will take up this value when it gets initialized.
                return jQuery( '#'+id ).val();
            }
        }
        return '';
    }

    $(".class-to-update-content").on("click", function(e) {
        myCustomSetContent( "tinymce-editor-id", "New Content in Editor" );
    });

    $(".class-to-get-content").on("click", function(e) {
        $("div.class-to-display-content").html( myCustomGetContent( "tinymce-editor-id" ) );
    });
});
```

Ref : http://blog.incognitech.in/tinymce-undefined-issue/

**EDIT:** Solution included